# PHP Printf As Float Precision

Tags: php, floating-point, printf, floating-accuracy

I am attempting to use PHP's `printf` function to print out a user's storage capacity. The full formula looks something like this:

```
echo printf("%.02f", ($size/(1024*1024))) . " GB";
```

Given that `$size == (10 * 1024 * 1024)`, this should print out

> 10.00 GB

But it doesn't. It prints `10.04 GB`. Furthermore,

```
echo printf("%.02f", 10)
```

results in

> 10.04

---

What?! In giving it an integer to convert to a float, it converts 10 to 10.00000009.

How can this be remedied? Obviously, one solution would be to print it out as an integer, but the value will not always be an integer; it may be 5.57 GB, in which case the accuracy of this script is very important.

---

And umm...

```
echo printf("%d", 10)
```

results in

> 102

Something is very wrong here.

Comment: You should really not use Print() and similar function together with Echo.

Comment: Why is `printf` echoed at all? `printf` already outputs the data to stdout. The `echo` is simply not needed. I see no problem here, save the fact the expressions and functions are used in a wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently `printf` is not meant to be echoed. At all.

Simply changing the instances of `printf` to `sprintf` fixed that problem.

---

Furthermore, removing the echo, and just running the command as `printf("%.02f", 10)` does, in fact, print `10.00`, however, it should be noted that you cannot append strings to printf like you can with echoing.

---

If you ask me, PHP should've thrown a syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION or something, but I digress.

Answer (score 0):

This is to deep, But I will try to explain:

```
echo printf("%d", 10)
```

TL>TR: When `echo` is called with an expression, it first evaluate all of the params, then displays the result on the screen.
If some of the expressions print something on the screen when evaluated, you get a this mess.

First thing that happens is `printf()` it is executed, to get its value.
This result in IMMEDIATELY printing "10" on the screen/output.

Then, the **return** result of `printf()` is echo-ed, in this case it is "2".
If you check the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) `printf` returns the **length** of the result string.

So on the screen you see  "10","2"

You should really not use **Print()** and similar function together with **Echo**.

P.S
Here is another gem:
`echo  1. print(2) + 3;`  // result: 214

Comment: **Why** would anyone use `echo printf` or `echo print` in first place? It's just silly to be honest. I see no reason why a language is to blame if it tries to fix something an incompetent programmer tries to do.

Comment: @Mjh  you are correct, the should not be used this way. But if you have a background in a more strict Programming Language it usually a shock when confronted with such specifics in PHP  :)